# How to stop user from selecting the same number once more?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have created an Array holding [24] data, and I assigned some information in each index. my problem is when I want to call the indexes using Scanner from the keyboard, let's say I called index[12]  from the user, next time I call it I want it to say, u already selected that number, choose a different number so on so forth. basically, I shouldn't call the same index twice, what is the best thing to use.

your help is much needed.

Comment: There are a couple of good ideas.  First is to store selections separately in another list/array and then querying that..

Comment: My preferred solutions would depend on the circumstances. Would you want to give the context for this requirement?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `java.util.Set` to store the selected indexed, for exmaple, [`java.util.HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).

It should look like:

```
Set<Integer> selected = new HashSet<>();

int userInput = ...; // get input from user

while (selected.contains(userInput)) {
    // print u already selected that number, choose a different number so on so forth
    userInput = ...; // get input from user
}


selected.add(userInput);

// do something with the index
```

Comment: The `add()` method itself returns false if the element is already present, so you can really just use that and remove `contains()`

Answer (score 0):

You must save the index of selected numbers, and then you make a comparison of all new numbers with your list's elements.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
    int choice = s.nextInt();
    List<Integer> choiced = new ArrayList<Integer>();


     while (true) {//or your condition
         label:
        for (Integer i : choiced) {
            if (choice == i) {
                System.out.println("Index already selected, please select a different one");
                break label;
            }
        }
        choiced.add(choice);

        choice = s.nextInt();
    }
```

Comment: Why would you not just use the `contains()` method?

Answer (score 0):

I tried both of your ways but still could solve it here is my code how would u have applied the codes that u guys wrote in here.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = 0;

    String [] differentChocolate = new String[24];
    differentChocolate[0]  = "You receive:  A star that weighs 7 grams";
    differentChocolate[1]  = "You receive:  Praline Bag Assorted 800g";
    differentChocolate[2]  = "You receive:  Kinder Surprise Santa 75g";
    differentChocolate[3]  = "You receive:  Woolworths Christmas Chocolate Net Bag 72g";
    differentChocolate[4]  = "You receive:  Quality Street Tub 726g";
    differentChocolate[5]  = "You receive:  Cadbury Favourites Snowman Bowl 700g";
    differentChocolate[6]  = "You receive:  Lindt Santa Pouch Bag 80g";
    differentChocolate[7]  = "You receive:  Praline Bag Assorted 800g";




    while (true){
        System.out.println("Choose a chocolate (0-23): ");
                number = in.nextInt();
                System.out.println(differentChocolate[number]);
            }
        }
    }
```